# Save and reload layout in Eclipse 4 RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, layout, eclipse-rcp

I am doing application using Eclipse 4 rcp. I general it is single perspective UI with layout based on `Part View's`, what allows me to drag, and reorder layout. Problem is that it is automatically persisted.

Is it possible to handle that process? I would like to create handler which would reset my layout to stock.

I saw tutorial here: [Eclipse 4 Model Persistence - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4ModelPersistence/article.html) but did not catch that point:

-Should I really override `ResourceHandler`.

-What is required to write hadlers like in example. Because line:

```
 E4XMIResourceFactory e4xmiResourceFactory = new E4XMIResourceFactory();
 Resource resource = e4xmiResourceFactory.createResource(null);
```

throws compile time exception:

```
The type org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIResourceFactoryImpl cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.
```

I maybe someone can explain or give a simple example, how to handle basic persistence of layout. Or at least hot to revert it to such, which was programmed

Answer (score 0):

Include the plugin `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi` in your plug-in's dependencies to resolve `XMIResourceFactoryImpl` (and `org.eclipse.emf.ecore` for `Resource`)

The author of this tutorial is one of the main Eclipse developers and his tutorials are usually accurate.

If you just want your application to always start with the original layout you can specify the `-clearPersistedState` option in the program arguments in your xxx.product file. You can also use `-persistState false` to stop the persistence of the model altogether.

Comment: Thank you for advice.
I believe that tutorial is accurate. Just it looks like too many steps to do, just to enable simple "Reset layout" action.

Comment: Well resetting part of the layout is not something that the designers thought about so it is not surprising that it is complex.

Comment: If you just want your app to always start in the same state you just use the -clearPersistedState flag.

Comment: No, there is point, I want to save the changed layout. But leave possibility to reset it.

Comment: I have already added plugins which you mention but I still get error with: `XMIResourceFactoryImpl `

Comment: All I can say is that it works fine here for me. Without `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi` I get the cannot be resolved message, adding it to the dependencies fixes it.